# curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_set, version CURL_OPENSSL_4

Tags: curl

I have been struggling a lot with curl in my machine (ubuntu 20.04) It's a dell for developers and came already with linux.

Since I got it I wasn't able to fix this issue and using wget instead.

Even if i only write `curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_set, version CURL_OPENSSL_4` I get this error.

If I run

```bash
$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl
```

So I know it is installed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Dell Latitude 5420, and fixed it running the following command, as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374621/curl-dynamic-linking-problem-in-21-10):

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove dca-enabler-packages dca-enabler
```